Flutterflow custom action to parse a JSON into a custom create data - issue
I built a custom action in flutter which aims to retrive a JSON from an algolia search
I then aim to take that JSON and break it down into a list of "hits" which is a custom created data type in flutterflow.
for some reason i am getting the error:
Instance of '_JsonMap': type '_JsonMap' is not a subtype of type 'List?'
I have read about it but i am unable to find a solution yet
the code is below:
import 'package:algolia/algolia.dart';

Future<List<HitsStruct>> convertJSONarrayToListOfHits(
    List<dynamic>? jsonArray) async {
  // Add your function code here!

  jsonArray ??= [];
  print("Number of items in jsonList: ${jsonArray.length}");

  final List<HitsStruct> hits = [];

  if (jsonArray.isNotEmpty) {
    for (var json in jsonArray) {
      HitsStruct hitItem = HitsStruct(
        chefIDref: json['hits']['chefIDref'],
        itemDescription: json['hits']['itemDescription'],
        name: json['hits']["name"],
        itemID: json['hits']["itemID"],
        cuisineType: json['hits']["cuisineType"],
        image: json['hits']["image"],
        price: json['hits']["price"],
        isActive: json['hits']["isActive"],
        objectID: json['hits']["objectID"],
        path: json['hits']["path"],
      );
      hits.add(hitItem);
    } //end for
  } // end if(jsonArray.isNotEmpty)
  return hits;
}

and my Json is below:
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "chefIDref": "12345678",
      "cuisineType": "Chinese",
      "image": "https://imagelink",
      "isActive": true,
      "itemDescription": "a delicious dish from hong kong with duck and also rice",
      "itemID": "OYM2JUsrlzAvOF8efkFh",
      "name": "HK Duck Rice",
      "price": 12,
      "path": "menuitem/O12345",
      "objectID": "12345"
    }
  ],
  "nbHits": 1,
  "page": 0,
  "nbPages": 1,
  "hitsPerPage": 20,
  "exhaustiveNbHits": true,
  "exhaustiveTypo": true,
  "exhaustive": {
    "nbHits": true,
    "typo": true
  },
  "query": "hk",
  "params": "query=hk",
  "renderingContent": {},
  "processingTimeMS": 2,
  "processingTimingsMS": {
    "_request": {
      "roundTrip": 2
    },
    "getIdx": {
      "load": {
        "total": 1
      },
      "total": 1
    },
    "total": 2
  },
  "serverTimeMS": 2
}

finally a screenshot of the custom data type i created
Please let me know whats wrong, im losing my head over this.
i tried the same code without the [hits]
i tried many other solutions and nothing worked. This is the first one that compiled alhtough i am still getting that error
